# Selenium IDE - Passing a URL string variable into a conditional 'gotoIf' statement throws a Syntax error?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to store the current url (http://example.com)in a variable and compare it with another string as a condition in the gotoIf command (part of the gotoIf extension.js):

```
    storeLocation || url
    gotoIf || ${url}=="http://example.com" || label
```

When I run this seleniun ide throws this error:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: message -> syntax error, fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///C:/Users/David%20Cunningham/Desktop/extensions_js/extensions.js, lineNumber -> 183, stack -> eval("http://example.com==\"http://example.com\"")@:0 ("http://example.com==\"http://example.com\"","label1")@chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///C:/Users/David%20Cunningham/Desktop/extensions_js/extensions.js:183 ("http://example.com==\"http://example.com\"","label1")@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium/scripts/htmlutils.js:60 ([object Object],[object Object])@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium/scripts/selenium-commandhandlers.js:310 ()@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:112 (6)@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:78 (6)@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium/scripts/htmlutils.js:60 , name -> SyntaxError
```

storeLocation should return a String so why am i getting this error, what is wrong with the syntax and how do I declare this command?

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows:

```
eval("http://example.com==\"http://example.com\"")
```

You should probably change your expression to:

```
gotoIf || "${url}"=="http://example.com" || label
```

So that you'll get a valid expression:

```
eval("\"http://example.com\"==\"http://example.com\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

yeap.. this works fine

```
gotoIf || "${x}"=="${y}"
```

Comment: It will be more helpful if you explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
try out this one   

 <tr>
        <td>storeLocation</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>echo</td>
        <td>${j}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>store</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
        <td>i</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>echo</td>
        <td>${i}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gotoIf</td>
        <td>storedVars['i']==storedVars['j']</td>
        <td>label</td>
    </tr>
```